# Questions about PJSUA and codec

Tags: python, asterisk, pjsip

I am using PJSIP 2.7 with Python on the Raspberrypi and I have 2 questions:

**Question 1:**

How am I supposed to know what codec is available?
I am using the **enum_codecs()** method to list the codec but it returns an array of hexadecimal string:

```
infos = lib.enum_codecs()
print infos

codec:[<pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2620>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2648>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2670>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2698>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c26c0>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c26e8>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2710>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2738>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2760>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2788>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c27b0>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c27d8>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2800>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2828>, <pjsua.CodecInfo instance at 0xb64c2850>]
```

How do I know which one is G711 and G722? I want my endpoint to use the G722 codec.
Doc about the classes is here: http://www.pjsip.org/python/pjsua.htm

---

**Question 2:**

Why do I get a device busy if I want to use the same audio device as pjsip in my Python code? I have also tried DMIX without success.

```
os.system("aplay -f S16_LE -c 2 -D plughw:1,0 /home/pi/beep.wav")
aplay: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found my answer for question 1 and 2:

The answer to question 1:
I can use the g722 codec by setting the right codec on the Asterisk's side.

The answer to question 2:

My mic was one usb device (hw 1) and my soundcard was another (hw 0).
I had to edit my .asound.conf file and use the dmix device for playback.
Here's my final working .asound.conf file:

```
pcm.!default
{
type asym
playback.pcm
{
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dmix"
}
capture.pcm 
{
    type plug
    slave.pcm "hw:1,0"
}
}
```

I can now playback sound while also being in the middle of a call with pjsua.
This post helped me to figure it out:

[Raspberry forum](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45500/how-to-configure-and-select-usb-microphone)